# How can I vertically align a TextField label?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I use TextField of matrial-ui and I change the height of field and after that label not adjust correctly:

[image]

I change the height using below codes:

```
<TextField
     *InputProps={{
      style : {height: height ?? ""}
    }}*
/>
```

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: You most probably have extra styles somewhere in your project that affects your label adjustment.

Answer (score 0):

```
<TextField
     *InputProps={{
      style : {height: height ?? "", justifyContent:"center"}
    }}*
/>
```

Comment: thanks , but problem not solve

Comment: Try:
textAlign: "center"

Comment: no , not work yet